# Two or more select option only first one works Ajax

Tags: javascript

This is my blade

```
<select name="{{$bank_invited_user->role}}[]" id="role" class="form-control">
    <option value="2" @if($bank_invited_user->role == 2) selected='selected' @endif >Co-author</option>
    <option value="3" @if($bank_invited_user->role == 3) selected='selected' @endif >Contributor</option>
    <option value="4" @if($bank_invited_user->role == 4) selected='selected' @endif >Guest</option>
    </select>
```

And here I have my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){ 

       $( "#role" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
        event.preventDefault();


        var role_value = $(this).val();
        var user_id = $("#role_id").val();
        var bank_id = $("#removecollaborator").val();

            $.ajax({

                method: "POST",
                url: "{{ url('/banks/change-role-in-bank') }}",
                data: {
                    _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                    role_value: role_value,
                    user_id: user_id,
                    bank_id:bank_id

                },
                success: function () {
                    $("select[id=role][value=" + role_value + "]");
                    alert('Role changed');
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log("error");
                }
            });
       });
    });  
</script>
```

When I click the the first select dropdown it changes just fine, but I have this select inside a foreach so it means I have more than one selections, so the other dropdown the second one it does not work.. I tried putting event.preventdefault but it does not work.. Can someone please help me, why the js code it does not work for the second selection(dropdown)..?

Comment: Where is your `foreach`.

Comment: Please add fiddle or snippet with your problem statement

Answer (score 0):

Can you check your brower console , mybe you have an ajax error

in js fiddle , the code is executed in the second event

https://jsfiddle.net/50k483nn/1/

You can also change event click to change for select dropdown

```
$( "#role" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
```

by

```
$( "#role" ).on( "change", function( event ) {
```